# Every time I resize my windows on the chrome my images move with it, thus overlapping text

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML, and css code:
Sorry If couldn't place the codes any better, but anyways when I re size my browser I always get those pictures to overlap texts, what I want is for those pictures to be fixed so when I re size the browser It doesnt overlap the text, and the pictures would just be moving out of the way to be positioned fixed, because It looks kind of ugly seeing text being overlapped.

```css
#wrapper{
 text-align:center;
    
}
body{
 margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:1200px;
 background-image:url("http://img15.deviantart.net/cbb9/i/2005/258/c/4/paper_texture_v5_by_bashcorpo.jpg");
 background-repeat:repeat-y;
 background-size: auto;
 margin-bottom:100px;
 background-attachment:fixed;
 font-family:traveling _typewriter;
 }
#wipe{
 margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
 font-weight:800;
 border:4px double;
 width:900px;
 
}
*{
 
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
}
img.img1{
 z-index:-1;
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 margin-left:20px;
 margin-top:25px;
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top: 0px;
}
img.img2{
 z-index:-1;
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 position:absolute;
 right:0px;
 top:0px;
 margin-top:25px;
 margin-right:20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>The 16th</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/copy.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
   <h1>Welcome to the 16th Infrantry Regiment!</h1>
  </div>
  
  <img src="http://webspace.webring.com/people/fc/czechandslovakthings/images/medals/meduk01ca.jpg" class="img1" />
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" class="img2"/>
  
   <table id="wipe">
   <td><a href="">Home<a/></td>
   <td><a href="">About Us</td>
   <td><a href="">Calendar</td>
   <td><a href="">Supply</td>
   <td><a href="">Enlist</td>
   <td><a href="">Forums</td>
   <td><a href="">PERSCOM</td>
   <td><a href="">Donate</td>
   </table>
   <div></div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Can we see some CSS?

Comment: use media queries for different resolution of screen.

Comment: Do you have any `<tr>` elements? Incorrect markup, especially when tables are involved, can cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: No I just used <td>s  tags

Comment: As you can when you run on snippet on full screen, and resize the windows the images move, and overlap content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix image overlapping add `position:relative` to your body tag.

Add this to your head tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

A `<meta>` viewport element gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.

The `width=device-width` part sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device (which will vary depending on the device).

The `initial-scale=1.0` part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser.

Comment: I did, it didn't resolve the issue. i imported like so.                                          <head>
   <title>The 16th</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/copy.css">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>

Comment: add position:relative; to your body tag, This will fix your issue. Here is the demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGoQKW

Comment: OMG Thank you! Sorry if my question seemed odd, the nights are usually the only times I have time to code, so im usually kind of tired already, or program thank you!

Comment: Glad that helped. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

img{width:100%;height:auto;}

or use bootstrap class="img-responsive"